# Find average using dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas

I have these columns in my dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

I need to find average of all the [Count] values where Day is `1` or `2` and so on.

I've tried that by using key dictionary:

```
col_dict = dict(zip(df6.Day, df6.Count))

k=2  # Enter Day
#print(k)
for keys in col_dict.keys():
    if keys == k:
        for i in col_dict:
            a=col_dict[keys] where col_dict==k
```

But I think this code is not correct.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so this might happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.4 - How to get the average of dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687244/python-3-4-how-to-get-the-average-of-dictionary-values)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has purpose-built methods for grouping and aggregating data. Here you can use `groupby` + `mean`:

```
res = df6.groupby('Day')['Count'].mean()
```

There is no need for dictionary conversion or explicit iteration when vectorised operations are available. If you need a dictionary result, you can convert in a separate step:

```
res_dict = res.to_dict()
```